# How to add trigger to Grid using code-behind

Tags: wpf, triggers, grid

I'm trying to add a trigger to a grid with a button in one of it's cell using the `IsMouseOverProperty` such that if the users mouse is over any part of the grid, the button appears and if outside the grid, disappears. I've been able to achieve this on `XAML`:

```
        <Grid Name="myGrid" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 20 0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
            <Button Content="buttonA" Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Button Content="buttonB" Background="Blue" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button Content="buttonC" Background="Red" Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
```

but having difficulty translating to `C#`. Essentially all three buttons are completely hidden till the users mouse hovers above any part of the grid. The grid creation, and accompanying trigger, depends on the user's action hence why I'm trying to write it in the code behind.

A sample code I've written is:

```
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
//create rows and columns, add to row and column definitions of myGrid
myGrid.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

Button button = new Button()
{
 Opacity = 0,
 //other button style 
};Grid.SetColumn(button, 0);Grid.SetRow(button, 0);myGrid.Children.Add(button);

Trigger trigger = new Trigger()
{
  SourceName = "myGrid",
  Property = Grid.IsMouseOverProperty,
  Value = true
 };
```

this works all good. I understand I have to wrap the `Trigger` in a `Style` before applying to `myGrid` but do I add the `Setter` to the `Trigger` or `Style`?

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(Grid));

trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(OpacityProperty, 1, "button"));
//or
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(OpacityProperty, 1, "myGrid"));

myGrid.Style = style;
myGrid.Style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

But I get the error "1" is not a valid value for `Opacity` property on a `Setter`.

Also would target field in `setter` be the grid or button, I've used button in this but neither works. I've also tried playing with the visibility property but then an error "After a 'TriggerCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified." comes up. I feel I'm missing something or implementing this the wrong way.

I've looked through most solutions on here but they seem to be in `XAML`.

Guidance or link will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to set the Visibility property of the button instead of the Opacity?

Comment: @tombobadil yeah, tried that when I kept getting the "1" error but didn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone else:

Seeing as the style is fixed irrespective of the users prior action, I can create it as a resource like so in XAML:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

and then reference from code behind:

```
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
//create rows and columns, add to row and column definitions of myGrid
myGrid.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

Button button = new Button()
{
 //button style 
};Grid.SetColumn(button, 0);Grid.SetRow(button, 0);myGrid.Children.Add(button);

myGrid.Style = (Style)FindResource("myStyle");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `Opacity` property to a `double` value, i.e. change `1` to `1.0`:

```
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(OpacityProperty, 1.0, "button"));
```

`1` is an `int` as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the "1" issue but I still get the error "A Style has no child nodes so a Style Setter cannot specify child node name 'button'.'"

Comment: A `Style` with a `TargetType` of `Grid` cannot set the property of a `Button`. It only makes sense to set `TargetName` in templates. It's unclear what you are trying to do. Please post your working XAML.

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistake on my part when posting code here. Added the XAML code which works.

Comment: Why are you accepting your own answer instead of the one that solved your original issue?